# How to resolve circular dependency in module using Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The project structure is like this

1. Main Module : This is the base App Code
2. Enhancement Module 1 : This is an addition of extra feature and it has it's own Activity and it uses some code from Main Module.
3. Enhancement Module 2 : Same as Module 1 but a separate developer is working on another feature. Also uses some code from Main Module.

Now as Module 1 and 2 has their own Activity which needs to be invoked from Main Module, there rises an problem with circular dependency. Main Module needs to invoke Activity from Module 1 and Module 1 needs some code from Main.

So how to resolve these kind of dependency problem in Android Studio using gradle ?

Comment: May be you should move all activities in one module(Main for example)? I think the only solution

Comment: So, it's bad practice to use chaotic dependencies. Please, read this article about clean architecture: http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/ and github repository of this article: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

Comment: Yes I know it's a bad practice but the reason is to separate one's work from another. So trying to find a solution if this kind of dependency can be resolved.

Comment: @SumitSahoo Have you found any solution? I am also facing same issue if YES can you please share you solution/answer.

Comment: Sadly no, but this kind of setup was not recommended anyways. Currently using MVVM and making the data flow from bottom up. I think this is right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Move the common code used by the two enhancement modules to another module, and create two application modules:

- `common`
- `enhancement 1` depends on `common`
- `enhancement 2` depends on `common`
- `app 1` depends on `enhancement 1`
- `app 2` depends on `enhancement 2`

If needed created another module `common-app` to contain the common code shared between the two applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via an implicit `Intent`. 
Let's say you want Activity1 in Module1 to start Activity2 in Module2, but you can't because that would cause a circular dependency. 
Go to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in Module2 and set `android:exported="true"` as a property on the Activity2. Then, in Activity1, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.module2", "com.example.module2.Activity2"));
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```